# How to add a customized link/url field in Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin

in Django admin.py, how to add a customized link/url field *download_pdf* into the admin view?

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'download_pdf']

    def full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name + " " + obj.last_name
    
    def download_pdf(self, obj):
        return "<a href=''>PDF</a>"  # this is not working
```

the above code is not working, the *download_pdf* field shows as text but not a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`format_html(...)`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'download_pdf']

    def full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name + " " + obj.last_name

    def download_pdf(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href=''>PDF")
```

Example:

```
def download_pdf(self, obj):
    return format_html(f"<a href='/foo/bar/{obj.pk}/download-pdf/'>PDF</a>")
```